# Cambios en proceso principal desde un task

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo una aplicación y quiero comprobar a través de un Task si el usuario abre otras aplicaciones y en ese caso minimizar mi aplicación (pero que la pueda seguir usando por eso el task).

El problema es que lanza una excepción

> ```
> System.InvalidOperationException: 'El subproceso que realiza la llamada no puede
> obtener acceso a este objeto porque el propietario es otro subproceso.'
> ```

Entiendo que a el estar en un subproceso no puedo gestionar el proceso principal, pero no se como solucionarlo.

```
Task checkProcess = new Task(() =>
{
   if( Process.GetProcesses().Count() > numOfProcess)
       WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
});
checkProcess.Start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solución:

```
Task checkProcess = new Task(() =>
{
   if( Process.GetProcesses().Count() > numOfProcess)
       this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
           WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        });
});
checkProcess.Start()
```

Con añadir `this.Dispatcher.Invoke` a lo que quieras hacer funciona perfectamente sin excepciones. +Info [Clase Dispatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Encontraste la solución despues o intentaste que sea una "guia" a modo de pregunta y autorespuesta? Igualmente, lee [answer] para redactar mejor la respuesta. Explica qué fallaba en la pregunta y como la respuesta lo soluciona. En 48h podrás marcar como aceptada la respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: Además de lo que comenta @lois6b, sería bueno añadir una explicación del código para que sea más útil.

Comment: Encontré la respuesta después, gracias.